# Send GridView Control to message's body

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a Gridview and i want when user click on a link , the gridview will be transffered to outlook message's body

I add a link like below

```
<a onclick="SendGrid()">SendEmail</a>
```

and create below JavaScript function to set the link .

```
 var SendGrid = function () {
      var grid = document.getElementById("myGridView").innerHTML;     
      var mailToLink = "mailto:someone@example.com?Body=" + encodeURIComponent(grid);
      window.location.href = mailToLink;
        }
```

Now when i click on SendEmail link , outlook opened but the GridView appeared in HTML tags (Not Formatted) , I search and found that it is impossible to format mailto Body because it accept only plain text

Is there any alternative solution ?

What i need is when user click on link , outlook opened and GridView displayed there !

I know that mail can be sent and GridView passed through MailMessage Class but i want to enable users to send the mail through outlook not through asp.net page

Comment: from the browser out, no, who says that all users have even a mail program installed. Why not send the gridview to the user who needs it, and then they can decide to whom they want to forward this data? Or, let the user send his emails from your website itself

Comment: It is not a published website , it is a small web application that will be accessed internally only , all PCs have the same version of outlook.

Comment: Then, maybe you should choose a different technology to enable this feature for your users?

Comment: This is an issue, You can't seem to get HTML to go in there. Other solutions would be to either have the grid put into an email to the user from the server. Or have the user get the grid in an excel download. But they you'll then have lots of extra work exporting Grids to proper excel workbooks to keep the formatting.